# How to calculate sum of all averages in the root process, local averages received from other processes in MPI programming?

Tags: c, mpi

The problem statement given is to
Write a MPI program (using C) to read an integer value M and NXM elements into an 1D array in the root process, where N is the number of processes. Root process sends M elements to each process. Each process finds average of M elements it received and sends these average values to root. Root collects all the values and finds the total average. Use collective communication routines.(Note:MPI_Reduce functions is not allowed)

My solution is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int rank,size,m,arr[10],ans[10];
    float avg = 0,sum=0;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    if (rank == 0){
        fprintf(stdout,"Enter m:\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        fprintf(stdout,"Enter %d elements:\n",size*m);
        fflush(stdout);
        for (int i = 0; i < size*m; i++)
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    
    MPI_Bcast(&m,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(arr, m, MPI_INT, ans, m, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        sum += ans[i];
    avg = sum/m;
    MPI_Gather(&avg, 1, MPI_FLOAT, ans, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            avg += ans[i];
        avg = avg/m;
        fprintf(stdout,"The  average of all values %f\n",avg);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Generated Output:

```
Enter m:
Enter 0 elements:
The  average of all values -1.#IND00
```

I'm not able to understand how I can proceed further to fix the error. As after the calling MPI_Gather function it should be able to calculate the average in the root process. Using MPI_Reduce would simplify this problem a lot but I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: Just before `if (rank == 0){` executes, what are the values of `size` and `m`?  I suspect at least one of them is zero.

Comment: The problem is I'm not able enter anything in the terminal when I run it. I didn't hardcode any values either so I'm not sure what exactly is happening.

Comment: Simply add `fprintf(stdout,"%d %d\n", size, m);` before `if (rank == 0){`.

Comment: The MPI-ish way is to use `MPI_Reduce()`. When summing the averages, there are two errors in this line : `for(int i=0; i<m; i++)`

Comment: you can enter the values in a file and then `mpirun ... < inputfile`, that being said, it is probably better to `fopen("inputfile", ...)` and read from there.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm not allowed to use MPI_Reduce() for solving the problem. My professor asked me to do it without using MPI_Reduce().

Comment: got it, my advices still stand.

Comment: I was able to solve it with MPI_Reduce() the problem is simpler to solve that way I do agree with you

Comment: did you fix your bugs first before moving to MPI_Reduce?

Comment: Yes I did I just had to add scanf statement which resulted in all the trouble thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, size, arr[10], recv[20],n;
    float avg = 0, sum = 0, tot_sum = 0, tot_avg = 0, ans[20];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Enter n:\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &n);
        fprintf(stdout, "Enter %d array elements:\n", n * size);
        fflush(stdout);
        for (int i = 0; i < n * size; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(arr, n, MPI_INT, recv, n, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += recv[i];  
    }
    avg = sum / n;
    
    fprintf(stdout, "Process (rank %d) has average %f\n", rank, avg);
    fflush(stdout);
    
    MPI_Gather(&avg, 1, MPI_FLOAT, ans, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {  
            tot_sum += ans[i];
        }
        tot_avg = tot_sum / size;  
        fprintf(stdout, "Total average: %f\n", tot_avg);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

Generated output
Enter n:
1
Enter 4 array elements:
1 2 3 4
Process (rank 0) has average 1.000000
Process (rank 2) has average 3.000000
Process (rank 1) has average 2.000000
Process (rank 3) has average 4.000000
Total average: 2.500000
```

This solution resolves the problem where we get garbage values. There was a problem with the previous solution where I used the wrong variables while calculating the averages.

Comment: Generally speaking, total_ans is still wrong

Comment: The new solution that I posted works